# UITableView delegate methods not being called. Created from another class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to add `UITableView` from another class but the `delegate` methods are not being called. Only the `numberOfRowsInSection` method is being called. I know I can do this in the main `ViewController`, but I would like to do it from another class. Is it possible? This code is fully functional, just copy and paste into a project. Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let t = Table()
        t.create()
    }
}

class Table: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private let myArray: NSArray = ["First","Second","Third"]

 func create() {
        let barHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        let displayWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let displayHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

        let myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barHeight, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight - barHeight))
        myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(myTableView)
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Num: \(indexPath.row)")
        print("Value: \(myArray[indexPath.row])")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("numberOfRowsInSection")
        return myArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("cellForRowAt")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(myArray[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: is TableView visible to your screen ?

Comment: Missing a `reloadData()` maybe?

Comment: Yes, the table view is visible on the screen, but the delegate methods are not responding. reloadData() does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let t = Table()
        t.create()
    }
}
```

You have created a ***local*** variable `t`. As soon as you leave the `viewDidLoad()` function, `t` no longer exists - so there are no delegate methods to call.

Instead, create a class-level variable that will stick around:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let t = Table()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        t.create()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not called due to it Tablview not added to self.view or else. so you need to add this line after setting of tableview.

```
func create() {
        let barHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        let displayWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let displayHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

        let myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barHeight, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight - barHeight))
        myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(myTableView)
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(myTableView) //add this line 
    }
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. I am trying to add this table to the rootViewController.